# finding an index to pointers to chars arrays

Tags: c, pointers

I'm using this countof macro

```
COUNT_OF(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(0[x])) / ((size_t)(!(sizeof(x) % sizeof(0[x])))))
```

which gives me the size of an array of chars like

```
char *ta[]={"asdf","qwer","zxcv"}
```

but it doesn't work when i use it in the scope of the function.

```
int indexof(char *aword, char *arrayofwords[]){
  int i; unsigned int ct=COUNT_OF(  (*???)  arrayofwords);
  for (i=0 ; i<ct ;i++){
    if (strcmp(aword,arrayofwords[i])==0){return i;}}
  return -1;//not found
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` is known as a *compile-time* operator. It can count sizes only of objects whose size can be determined before-hand. So when you pass it a pointer (arrays degenerate to pointers when passed as function arguments), you just get the size of the pointer.

A typical arrangement is to end the list with a NULL pointer. With such a list, your function could be written this way:

```
int indexof(char *aword, char *arrayofwords[]){
  int i;
  for (i=0 ; arrayofwords[i]!=NULL ;i++){
    if (strcmp(aword,arrayofwords[i])==0){return i;}}
  return -1;//not found
}
```

This may indeed appear surprising because the following does work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COUNT_OF(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(0[x])) / ((size_t)(!(sizeof(x) % sizeof(0[x])))))

int main() {
char *ta[]={"asdf","qwer","zxcv"};
char *aword="qwer";
  int i; unsigned int ct=COUNT_OF(ta);
  for (i=0 ; i<ct ;i++){
    if (strcmp(aword,ta[i])==0){return i;}}
  return -1;//not found
}
```

This is because the array `ta` is defined in the same scope in which `sizeof` is being applied to it. Since `sizeof` performs its calculation at *compile-time*, it can use the compiler's symbol table to discover exactly how much space has been allocated for each of these pieces.

But, when you pass it to a function, it is no longer an array so far as the compiler is concerned. The `indexof` function cannot use `sizeof` to discover the size of the array passed, because inside of this function it is not an array, it is just a pointer (char ** == char *[] == char [][]).

One way to make use of your `COUNT_OF` macro, would be to make `indexof` accept a length parameter. Then you can use `COUNT_OF` in the call (so long as the array concerned is defined in scope).

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COUNT_OF(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(0[x])) / ((size_t)(!(sizeof(x) % sizeof(0[x])))))

int main() {
char *ta[]={"asdf","qwer","zxcv"};
char *word="qwer";
  return indexof(word, ta, COUNT_OF(ta));
}

int indexof(char *aword, char *arrayofwords[], int length){

  int i; unsigned int ct=length;
  for (i=0 ; i<ct ;i++){
    if (strcmp(aword,arrayofwords[i])==0){return i;}}
  return -1;//not found
}
```

Comment: but why does it work in the scope of main but not in the function?

Comment: Updated to address your follow-up.

Comment: thanks!
 i've seen the NULL and length solutions before but they seem extraneous and I feel like there should be some way to do count at runtime.
(I'm coming from Python..so I demand maximum functionality and elegance from C..but it seems like it's always a battle!)

Answer (score 0):

@majidaldosari: I guess the problem is in your macro 
**COUNT_OF(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(0[x])) / ((size_t)(!(sizeof(x) % sizeof(0[x])))))**

which should have been

**COUNT_OF(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])) / ((size_t)(!(sizeof(x) % sizeof(x[0])))))**